# XSLT 2.0 - How to apply grouping and tokenize for transforming the XML

Tags: group-by, xslt-2.0, tokenize

I have an input XML which contains same repeating node with varying text. The text is actually delimited by `~`, similar to `csv`. The text in the `data` row starts with `D` whereas the text in the `total` row is represented by `T`. The `data` row is repeated multiple times and will be followed by a row containing the totals when the record type changes.

Sample XML

```
<ResponseData>
    <Row>D~1.CASA~1006.22</Row>
    <Row>T~1.CASA~1006.22</Row>
    <Row>D~2.DEPOSIT~763000.00</Row>
    <Row>D~2.DEPOSIT~1217800.00</Row>
    <Row>D~2.DEPOSIT~941100.00</Row>
    <Row>T~2.DEPOSIT~2921900.00</Row>
    <Row>D~3.CCOD~269056041.30</Row>
    <Row>T~3.CCOD~269056041.30</Row>
    <Row>D~4.TERM LOAN~4496897.00</Row>
    <Row>D~4.TERM LOAN~15950106.00</Row>
    <Row>T~4.TERM LOAN~20447003.00</Row>
</ResponseData>
```

I need to group by the records having the same record type viz. `1.CASA`, `2.DEPOSIT`, etc. within an element and they would be followed by the `total` value as shown the expected output XML below.

Desired Output

```
<Output>
    <accountList>
        <accountDetails>
            <rowType>D</rowType>
            <recordType>CASA</recordType>
            <balanceAmt>1006.22</balanceAmt>
        </accountDetails>
        <recordType>CASA</recordType>
        <ttlBalAmt>1006.22</ttlBalAmt>
    </accountList>
    <accountList>
        <accountDetails>
            <rowType>D</rowType>
            <recordType>DEPOSIT</recordType>
            <balanceAmt>763000.00</balanceAmt>
        </accountDetails>
        <accountDetails>
            <rowType>D</rowType>
            <recordType>DEPOSIT</recordType>
            <balanceAmt>1217800.00</balanceAmt>
        </accountDetails>
        <accountDetails>
            <rowType>D</rowType>
            <recordType>DEPOSIT</recordType>
            <balanceAmt>941100.00</balanceAmt>
        </accountDetails>
        <recordType>DEPOSIT</recordType>
        <ttlBalAmt>2921900.00</ttlBalAmt>
    </accountList>
    <accountList>
        <accountDetails>
            <rowType>D</rowType>
            <recordType>CCOD</recordType>
            <balanceAmt>269056041.30</balanceAmt>
        </accountDetails>
        <recordType>CCOD</recordType>
        <ttlBalAmt>269056041.30</ttlBalAmt>
    </accountList>
    <accountList>
        <accountDetails>
            <rowType>D</rowType>
            <recordType>TERM LOAN</recordType>
            <balanceAmt>4496897.00</balanceAmt>
        </accountDetails>
        <accountDetails>
            <rowType>D</rowType>
            <recordType>TERM LOAN</recordType>
            <balanceAmt>15950106.00</balanceAmt>
        </accountDetails>
        <recordType>TERM LOAN</recordType>
        <ttlBalAmt>20447003.00</ttlBalAmt>
    </accountList>
</Output>
```

I am using `XSLT 2.0` and am stuck on applying grouping on the tokenized variable. Below is my attempt.

XSLT

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    exclude-result-prefixes="xs">

    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="no" omit-xml-declaration="yes" />
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*" />
    
    <!-- Global variables -->
    <!-- Variable for capturing the data records -->
    <xsl:variable name="recordData">
        <elementName index="1" name="rowType" />
        <elementName index="2" name="recordType" />
        <elementName index="3" name="balanceAmt" />
    </xsl:variable>
    
    <!-- Variable for capturing the sub-total records -->
    <xsl:variable name="subTotalData">
        <elementName index="2" name="recordType" />
        <elementName index="3" name="ttlBalAmt" />
    </xsl:variable>

    <xsl:template match="ResponseData">
        <Output>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="Row"/>
        </Output>
    </xsl:template>
    
    <!-- Match template for record elements i.e. repeating data and sub-totals -->
    <xsl:template match="Row">
        <xsl:variable name="record" select="tokenize(., '~')" />
        <accountList>
            <xsl:choose>
                <xsl:when test="$record[1] = 'D'">
                    <accountDetails>
                        <xsl:for-each select="$record">
                            <xsl:variable name="dataIdx" select="position()" />
                            <xsl:if test="exists($recordData/elementName[@index = $dataIdx])">
                                <xsl:choose>
                                    <xsl:when test="$recordData/elementName[@index = $dataIdx]">
                                        <xsl:if test="$dataIdx = 2">
                                            <xsl:call-template name="prepElement">
                                                <xsl:with-param name="nodeName" select="$recordData/elementName[@index = $dataIdx]/@name" />
                                                <xsl:with-param name="nodeValue" select="substring(., 3)" />
                                            </xsl:call-template>
                                        </xsl:if>
                                        <xsl:if test="$dataIdx != 2">
                                            <xsl:call-template name="prepElement">
                                                <xsl:with-param name="nodeName" select="$recordData/elementName[@index = $dataIdx]/@name" />
                                                <xsl:with-param name="nodeValue" select="." />
                                            </xsl:call-template>
                                        </xsl:if>
                                    </xsl:when>
                                </xsl:choose>                           
                            </xsl:if>
                        </xsl:for-each>
                    </accountDetails>
                </xsl:when>
                <xsl:when test="$record[1] = 'T'">
                    <xsl:for-each select="$record">
                        <xsl:variable name="dataIdx" select="position()" />
                        <xsl:if test="exists($subTotalData/elementName[@index = $dataIdx])">
                            <xsl:choose>
                                <xsl:when test="$subTotalData/elementName[@index = $dataIdx]">
                                    <xsl:if test="$dataIdx = 2">
                                        <xsl:call-template name="prepElement">
                                            <xsl:with-param name="nodeName" select="$subTotalData/elementName[@index = $dataIdx]/@name" />
                                            <xsl:with-param name="nodeValue" select="substring(., 3)" />
                                        </xsl:call-template>
                                    </xsl:if>
                                    <xsl:if test="$dataIdx != 2">
                                        <xsl:call-template name="prepElement">
                                            <xsl:with-param name="nodeName" select="$subTotalData/elementName[@index = $dataIdx]/@name" />
                                            <xsl:with-param name="nodeValue" select="." />
                                        </xsl:call-template>
                                    </xsl:if>
                                </xsl:when>
                            </xsl:choose>                           
                        </xsl:if>
                    </xsl:for-each>
                </xsl:when>
            </xsl:choose>
        </accountList>
    </xsl:template>
    
    <!-- Template to prepare the element -->
    <xsl:template name="prepElement">
        <xsl:param name="nodeName" />
        <xsl:param name="nodeValue" />
        
        <xsl:element name="{$nodeName}">
            <xsl:value-of select="$nodeValue" />
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Any help is appreciated. I have trimmed down the sample XML text (3 tokens) to simplify the example. The value in the node can be tokenized into about 17-18 tokens.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The supported versions of XSLT processor like SaxonJ or SaxonC or SaxonJS all support XSLT 3 these days so if you are a Saxon user you can use XSLT 3 and e.g. tokenize the values into an array and access the array; the data seems grouped except for the identification of the "total" row, that is easily done with `for-each-group group-ending-with`:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    exclude-result-prefixes="#all"
    expand-text="yes"
    version="3.0">

  <xsl:output indent="yes"/>
  
  <xsl:template match="ResponseData">
    <Output>
      <xsl:for-each-group select="Row ! array { tokenize(., '~') }" group-ending-with=".[?1 = 'T']">
        <accountList>
          <xsl:apply-templates select="current-group()[position() lt last()]"/>
          <xsl:apply-templates select="current-group()[last()]" mode="total"/>
        </accountList>
      </xsl:for-each-group>
    </Output>
  </xsl:template>
  
  <xsl:template match=".[. instance of array(*)]">
    <accountDetails>
      <rowType>{?1}</rowType>
      <recordType>{?2 => substring-after('.')}</recordType>
      <balanceAmt>{?3}</balanceAmt>
    </accountDetails>
  </xsl:template>
  
  <xsl:template match=".[. instance of array(*)]" mode="total">
    <accountDetails>
      <recordType>{?2 => substring-after('.')}</recordType>
      <ttlBalAmt>{?3}</ttlBalAmt>
    </accountDetails>
  </xsl:template>
  
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

For XSLT 2 you can use

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    exclude-result-prefixes="xs"
    version="2.0">

  <xsl:output indent="yes"/>
  
  <xsl:template match="Row" mode="tokenize">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:for-each select="tokenize(., '~')">
        <Col>
          <xsl:value-of select="."/>
        </Col>
      </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
  
  <xsl:template match="ResponseData">
    <xsl:variable name="tokenized-data">
      <xsl:apply-templates select="Row" mode="tokenize"/>
    </xsl:variable>
    <Output>
      <xsl:for-each-group select="$tokenized-data/Row" group-ending-with="Col[1][. = 'T']">
        <accountList>
          <xsl:apply-templates select="current-group()[position() lt last()]"/>
          <xsl:apply-templates select="current-group()[last()]" mode="total"/>
        </accountList>
      </xsl:for-each-group>
    </Output>
  </xsl:template>
  
  <xsl:template match="Row">
    <accountDetails>
      <rowType>
        <xsl:value-of select="Col[1]"/>
      </rowType>
      <recordType>
        <xsl:value-of select="substring-after(Col[2], '.')"/>
      </recordType>
      <balanceAmt>
        <xsl:value-of select="Col[3]"/>
      </balanceAmt>
    </accountDetails>
  </xsl:template>
  
  <xsl:template match="Row" mode="total">
    <accountDetails>
      <recordType>
        <xsl:value-of select="substring-after(Col[2], '.')"/>
      </recordType>
      <ttlBalAmt>
        <xsl:value-of select="Col[3]"/>
      </ttlBalAmt>
    </accountDetails>
  </xsl:template>
  
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, however I am using `XSLT 2.0` and not sure whether the above solution would work since it is using `version 3.0`. Is it possible to do this in `XSLT 2.0`?

Comment: Well, do you really use an XSLT processor that only supports 2.0 but not 3.0? As I said, all supported versions of e.g. Saxon support 3.0 anyway. As for doing it in XSLT 2.0, there you can't use an array but can of course convert the tokens into XML elements and group them.